# Get specific column from a csv file in QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, csv

I want to extract data from a particular column in .csv file. 
I can extract the first column by using `.first()` but how to extract the data from 7th or 9th column.

```
static void ReadCSVData(QString fileName, std::vector<float>& data) {
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;

    file.readLine(); // read first line and ignore
    while (!file.atEnd()) {
        QString line = file.readLine(); // read wavelength line and store it
        QString fields = line.split(',').first();
        data.push_back(fields.toFloat());
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Is there any way I can get whole data as a `vector` and by passing the column number I can get data for that particular column?

Comment: The [`split`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split) function returns [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) which inherits from [`QList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) which have a pair of [array-indexing operators (`[]`)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d). That should give you a good enough hint about how to get a specific column.

Comment: On a totally unrelated (to your problem) note, reading CSV files is *deceptively* simple. To properly handle such a file one have to be able to handle some very tricky corner- and special-cases. For example, what if you have a quoted string containing a `','` without it being a field separator? That's why I always recommend you try to find a library to handle it all for you (it might even be possible that Qt have such special code already).

Comment: _"I can extract the first column..."_  Not always.  `"Chicago, IL", 60610` is valid csv, but would be read incorrectly with the code you show.

Comment: Hey, did my answer solve your problem or it was completely off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as using `QString::split()` to get your list of columns.

```
const QStringList fields { line.split(',') };
const QString column3 { fields[2] };
```

That said, I suggest don't reinvent the wheel: use a CSV parsing library that has been tested and covers the corner cases. Surprisingly, Qt offers no support for such a common format so I recommend [qtcsv](https://github.com/iamantony/qtcsv).